# Include RecycleViewsHolders in Activity Java Code

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a recycle view in which I had to implement the holder and adapter classes within the activity class itself in order to execute this statement:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
 
         if (pulsado == 0) {
             pulsado = 1;
             fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            if (getAdapterPosition()==0) {
                 miPlan.setHodratacion(1);
          
            }

         } else {
             pulsado = 0;
             fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
             countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
 
             if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                miPlan.setHodratacion(0);
         }
 
     }
```

My problem is that when I click on any item in the Recycle View only the background color of the last item is changed, and not the side. There must be some error in the holder that I cannot discover

This is the code:

```
public class NueMatInvernales extends Activity {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
private Plan miPlan;


public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RelativeLayout fondo;
public int pulsado=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_mat);

    miPlan = new Plan();
    miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

    setTitle(null);

    ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

    siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();

            passIntent.setClass(NueMatInvernales.this, NuevoAvaInf.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });


    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(NueMatInvernales.this, 5);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NueMatInvernales.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Pala", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Martillo", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Casco", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Paleta", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Espuerta", R.drawable.icon));  
 
    return allItems;


}

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {
    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

}

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (pulsado == 0) {
            pulsado = 1;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            if (getAdapterPosition()==0) {
                miPlan.setHodratacion(1);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Hidratación = " + miPlan.getHidratacion(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            pulsado = 0;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));

            if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                miPlan.setHodratacion(0);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don´t understand the problem... could you explain what do you want to do, please? Thanks!

Comment: i edit the post

Comment: I think the tabulations in the example code are bad and it is difficult to read them... but for example, the error: "Required type:OnClickListener Provided:NueMatInvernales" is because the "this" of itemView.setOnClickListener(this) is the NueMatInvernales but is required a OnClickListener so you need to implement in this class the View.OnClickListener interface

Comment: I have edited the entire post, I think the explanation and the code is clearer, if not, tell me and I will try to improve it

Comment: Ok, so if the problem is: Change the background color always i touch any item, not only the last? is it ok? in this case a solution could be the next: Add a boolean param named hasMainBackgroundColor, true by default and when you populate your recyclerView, use this value to show the background color.  When the user clicks on any item, create a copy of List<ItemObject> with this value to false,and pass to the recycler updating the info (notifyDataSetChanged).  If you use a Presenter/ViewModel, this presentation logic is doing by themself.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Android, could you tell me where to look for an example of that code or where to look for it?

Comment: Yes, the most important is to understand how it works a viewholder and the adapter, so you can to read about it in the official android page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview And I recommend you to buy the last version of book "Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I finally solved the problem by changing these statements:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
            holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
            holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
        }
```

Anyway I leave the correct code complete in case someone wants to take advantage of it

```
public class NueMatInvernales extends Activity {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
private Plan miPlan;


public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RelativeLayout fondo;
public int pulsado=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_mat);

    miPlan = new Plan();
    miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

    setTitle(null);

    ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

    siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();

            passIntent.setClass(NueMatInvernales.this, NuevoAvaInf.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });


    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(NueMatInvernales.this, 5);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NueMatInvernales.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Pala", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Martillo", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Casco", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Paleta", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Espuerta", R.drawable.icon));  
 
    return allItems;


}

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {
    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

}

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (pulsado == 0) {
            pulsado = 1;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            if (getAdapterPosition()==0) {
                miPlan.setHodratacion(1);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Hidratación = " + miPlan.getHidratacion(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            pulsado = 0;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));

            if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                miPlan.setHodratacion(0);
        }

    }
}
```